# Coroutines unit tests pass individually but not when run together

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have two coroutines tests that both pass when run individually, but if I run them together the second one always fails (even if I switch them around!). The error I get is:

> Wanted but not invoked: observer.onChanged([SomeObject(someValue=test2)]);
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

There's probably something fundamental I don't understand about coroutines (or testing in general) and doing something wrong.

If I debug the tests I find that the failing test is not waiting for the  inner `runBlocking` to complete. Actually the reason I have the inner `runBlocking` in the first place is to solve this exact problem and it seemed to work for individual tests.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

### Test class

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class ViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    private lateinit var mainThreadSurrogate: ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher

    @Mock
    lateinit var repository: DataSource
    @Mock
    lateinit var observer: Observer<List<SomeObject>>

    private lateinit var viewModel: SomeViewModel


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")
        Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)
        viewModel = SomeViewModel(repository)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun `loadObjects1 should get objects1`() = runBlocking {
        viewModel.someObjects1.observeForever(observer)
        val expectedResult = listOf(SomeObject("test1")) 
        `when`(repository.getSomeObjects1Async())
        .thenReturn(expectedResult)

        runBlocking {
            viewModel.loadSomeobjects1()
        }

        verify(observer).onChanged(listOf(SomeObject("test1")))
    }

    @Test
    fun `loadObjects2 should get objects2`() = runBlocking {
        viewModel.someObjects2.observeForever(observer)
        val expectedResult = listOf(SomeObject("test2"))
        `when`(repository.getSomeObjects2Async())
        .thenReturn(expectedResult)

        runBlocking {
            viewModel.loadSomeObjects2()
        }

        verify(observer).onChanged(listOf(SomeObject("test2")))
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class SomeViewModel constructor(private val repository: DataSource) : 
    ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main

    private var objects1Job: Job? = null
    private var objects2Job: Job? = null
    val someObjects1 = MutableLiveData<List<SomeObject>>()
    val someObjects2 = MutableLiveData<List<SomeObject>>()

    fun loadSomeObjects1() {
        objects1Job = launch {
            val objects1Result = repository.getSomeObjects1Async()
            objects1.value = objects1Result
        }
    }

    fun loadSomeObjects2() {
        objects2Job = launch {
            val objects2Result = repository.getSomeObjects2Async()
            objects2.value = objects2Result
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        objects1Job?.cancel()
        objects2Job?.cancel()
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
class Repository(private val remoteDataSource: DataSource) : DataSource {

    override suspend fun getSomeObjects1Async(): List<SomeObject> {
        return remoteDataSource.getSomeObjects1Async()
    }

    override suspend fun getSomeObjects2Async(): List<SomeObject> {
        return remoteDataSource.getSomeObjects2Async()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use `launch`, you're creating a coroutine which will execute *asynchronously*.  Using `runBlocking` does nothing to affect that.

Your tests are failing because the stuff inside your launches *will happen*, but hasn't happened yet.

The simplest way to ensure that your launches have executed before doing any assertions is to call `.join()` on them.

```
fun someLaunch() : Job = launch {
  foo()
}

@Test
fun `test some launch`() = runBlocking {
  someLaunch().join()

  verify { foo() }
}
```

Instead of saving off individual `Jobs` in your `ViewModel`, in `onCleared()` you can implement your `CoroutineScope` like so:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
  private val job = SupervisorJob()
  override val coroutineContext : CoroutineContext
    get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

  override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    job.cancel()
  }
}
```

All launches which happen within a `CoroutineScope` become children of that `CoroutineScope`, so if you cancel that `job` (which is effectively cancelling the `CoroutineScope`), then you cancel all coroutines executing within that scope.

So, once you've cleaned up your `CoroutineScope` implementation, you can make your `ViewModel` functions just return `Job`s:

```
fun loadSomeObjects1() = launch {
    val objects1Result = repository.getSomeObjects1Async()
    objects1.value = objects1Result
}
```

and now you can test them easily with a `.join()`:

```
@Test
fun `loadObjects1 should get objects1`() = runBlocking {
    viewModel.someObjects1.observeForever(observer)
    val expectedResult = listOf(SomeObject("test1")) 
    `when`(repository.getSomeObjects1Async())
    .thenReturn(expectedResult)

    viewModel.loadSomeobjects1().join()

    verify(observer).onChanged(listOf(SomeObject("test1")))
}
```

I also noticed that you're using `Dispatchers.Main` for your `ViewModel`.  This means that you will by default execute all coroutines on the main thread.  You should think about whether that's really something that you want to do.  After all, very few non-UI things in Android need to be done on the main thread, and your ViewModel shouldn't be manipulating the UI directly.

Comment: Wow thanks. It works! Coroutines guru with only 28 points. Better add some for you :)